# Subfigure places images vertically instead of horizontal

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats, subcaption

I want to place three images in one row using subfigure because the third image needs a different caption. Here's the code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.31\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figs/pct.pdf}
        \caption{MNLI}
        \label{fig:pct}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.31\textwidth}
        % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/seeds.pdf}
        \caption{Progressive}
        \label{fig:seeds_hans}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.31\textwidth}
        % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figs/c.pdf}
        \label{fig:c}
        \caption{clusters.}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Sampling with BERT}
\label{fig:progress}
\end{figure}
```

It places all images vertically for some reason.

Comment: Try [width=\linewidth] for all of the tree pictures?

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. It's a 2 column latex template in case you want to know.

Comment: Always place the `\label` after the corresponding `\caption`.

Comment: @kl_divergence do you then want the figures to stay in one column or go through both across the page? Could you try \textwidth instead of \linewidth?

Comment: Apart from that, please prepare a complete but small example document showing that Colo's suggestion does not work. If I try to prepare such an example based on the information you provided so far, I get the expected output.

Comment: I want the images to be placed side to side. Like .33% space given to all three figures. I have tried both with linewidth and textwidth. It stays in vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a two column document, you need to use `figure*`.  However, `figure*` only supports [tp] (and [b] with the dblfloatfix package), not [h].  Also note that it always moves to the next page, not the top of this page.

The [b] option for subfigure will align the captions (last baseline), while the [t] option will align the bottoms of the images (first baseline).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[tp]
%\centering% has no effect after \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.31\textwidth}
        %\centering% image and caption both fill entire space
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{MNLI}\label{fig:pct}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.31\textwidth}
        % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Progressive}\label{fig:seeds_hans}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.31\textwidth}
        % \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{clusters.}\label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Sampling with BERT}
\label{fig:progress}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to do that with `floatrow`, more specifically its `subfloatrow` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption, floatrow}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
        \centering
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{MNLI} \label{fig:pct}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
        \ffigbox{\caption{Progressive} \label{fig:seeds_hans}} {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{clusters.}\label{fig:c}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
\caption{Sampling with BERT-base on MNLI and HANS}
\label{fig:progressive_subsampling}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They are now in one column and very small. I want them to span across both columns.

Comment: Other thing is that the figure appears where its defined, but I want it to automatically take the top of next page like the standard behaviour of `figure`.

Comment: You didn't mention you're in two columns. Try with the `figure*` environment. It automatically goes where you want, but I'm not sure it works with `floatrow`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Comment: Wondering why subcaption approach wasn't working ?

Comment: It was working for me with your code (minimally completed), but the horizontal alignment of the figures was not too good. Anyway, floatrow cooperates with `caption` and `subcaption`. Probably you have an interaction with another package or code in your document?

Comment: Individual captions are coming, but caption and label of the figure as a whole is not coming with this method.

Comment: In your case also, caption and figure number doesn't show up as a whole for entire figure.